# HTML5-Video crashes with "Surface Texture is abondoned" in Webview

Tags: android, html, video, webview

I created a webview in Android Studio with WebChromeClient and hardware accelaration turned on to play HTML5 videos in a custom playlist.

Everything works fine for days, but when i leave the activity, i.e. to open a second one, and come back to the webview, most of the videos crashes after a while. The sound goes on, but the screen turns black.

At the same time the logcat returns "E/SurfaceTexture﹕ [unnamed-6010-15498] updateTexImage: SurfaceTexture is abandoned!".

My question now is: Is this an hardware issue and if so - why didn't it occur the first time i start the webview?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
  android:name=".App"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/General_Appinfo_Label"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity
  android:name=".Webview"
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
  android:label="@string/General_Appinfo_Label"
  android:noHistory="true"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
  <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="de.neolino.smartesign.Webview" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Webview.class (excerpt):

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
App.webview = new WebView(this);
WebChromeClient chromeClient = new WebChromeClient();
App.webview.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
windowContext = getWindow(); // for later use
decorViewWebview = windowContext.getDecorView();
final int uiOptions =(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
decorViewWebview.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
WebSettings webSettings = App.webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
App.webview.clearCache(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
setContentView(App.webview);    
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
App.webview.loadUrl(Pref.getString("SettingsWebviewTargetDialog"));
```

Logcat:

```
02-16 10:02:50.707    2678-9854/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ Stop Player.
02-16 10:02:50.757    2678-9854/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> free handle: 0x4c932b78, paddr: 0x4762b000, vaddr: 0x44f01000
02-16 10:02:50.757    2678-9854/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> free handle: 0x4c932b50, paddr: 0x48210000, vaddr: 0x45ae6000
02-16 10:02:50.757    2678-9854/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> free handle: 0x4c93da30, paddr: 0x48710000, vaddr: 0x45fe6000
02-16 10:02:50.777    2678-2939/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ Loading content: sharedfd://24:0:27399381:0
02-16 10:02:50.777    2678-2939/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ LEVEL: 1 FUNCTION: MediaTypeInspect LINE: 1656
02-16 10:02:50.777    2678-2939/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ Can't inspect media content type by subfix.
02-16 10:02:50.807   2678-20974/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ LEVEL: 1 FUNCTION: prepare LINE: 422
02-16 10:02:50.807   2678-20974/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ failed to open file: /data/system/audio_pass_through_pref.
02-16 10:02:50.807   2678-20974/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ Can't open library: lib_aacplusd_wrap_arm12_elinux_android.so
02-16 10:02:50.807   2678-20974/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "lib_aacplusd_wrap_arm12_elinux_android.so" not found
02-16 10:02:50.807    6010-6010/de.neolino.smartesign E/SurfaceTexture﹕ [unnamed-6010-15654] updateTexImage: SurfaceTexture is abandoned!
02-16 10:02:50.837   2678-20974/? I/vpu-lib﹕ Product Info: i.MX6Q/D/S
02-16 10:02:50.847   2678-20974/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ VideoRender role: video_render.surface
02-16 10:02:50.847   2678-20975/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ nPreCacheSize = 913312
02-16 10:02:50.877   2678-20974/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> alloc handle: 0x4c15fdf0, paddr: 0x47232000, vaddr: 0x44b08000
02-16 10:02:50.887   2678-20974/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> alloc handle: 0x4c15fe68, paddr: 0x47385000, vaddr: 0x44c5b000
02-16 10:02:50.887   2678-20974/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> alloc handle: 0x4c15ff10, paddr: 0x474d8000, vaddr: 0x44dae000
02-16 10:02:50.887   2678-20978/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> alloc handle: 0x4c15ff68, paddr: 0x48210000, vaddr: 0x45ae6000
02-16 10:02:50.887   2678-20978/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> alloc handle: 0x4c15ff90, paddr: 0x4762b000, vaddr: 0x44f01000
02-16 10:02:50.887   2678-20978/? I/vpu-lib﹕ bitstreamMode 1, chromaInterleave 1, mapType 0, tiled2LinearEnable 0
02-16 10:02:50.887   2678-20978/? W/vpu-lib﹕ VPU iram is less than needed, some parts don't use iram
02-16 10:02:50.897   2678-20974/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> free handle: 0x4c15fdf0, paddr: 0x47232000, vaddr: 0x44b08000
02-16 10:02:50.897   2678-20974/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> free handle: 0x4c15fe68, paddr: 0x47385000, vaddr: 0x44c5b000
02-16 10:02:50.897   2678-20974/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> free handle: 0x4c15ff10, paddr: 0x474d8000, vaddr: 0x44dae000
02-16 10:02:50.927   2678-20978/? I/vpu-lib﹕ <gpu> alloc handle: 0x4c768570, paddr: 0x48710000, vaddr: 0x45fe6000
02-16 10:02:50.927   2678-20974/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ Seek to 0
02-16 10:02:50.947    2678-9855/? I/OMXPlayer﹕ start player.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the the solution was a matter of timing.

I changed the local data with an IntentService in background. After that I closed the Webview and started it again. But the Surface Texture didn't seem to realize this fast enough or didn't rebuild at all.

A simple `webview.reload()` resp. `webview.loadUrl()` in case of starting a new instance of Webview did the trick.

Since Android 4.4 you have to perform this in the same thread the Webview runs in. To do it from outside the Webview's thread - i.e. a function - you have to build a global Webview object and call it like this:

```
App.webview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      App.webview.loadUrl("file://" + someLocalFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
});
```